# Detect device's enter key IonSearchBar

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

What I’m looking for is to run the Search function when the device’s enter key is pressed but I can’t do it. If with onIonChange I can filter the words

What event is necessary to use to detect the enter on the device? onIonInput does not works to detects enter key

```
const Search = () =>{
  //do something
   }   
const Words = (value:any) =>{
  //do something
   }   
     return(
    <>
      <IonSearchbar debounce={500} type="text" onIonChange={e => {Words(e.detail.value!)}} onIonInput={ Search} ></IonSearchbar>
    </>
     )
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `onKeyPress` with `event.key` to listen for the enter to key.

```
const keypress = (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter') {
    // Run search function
  }
}  
     
return(
  <>
   <IonSearchbar onKeyPress={keypress}></IonSearchbar>
  </>
)};
```